# How to mock packageManager.queryIntentActivities in Robolectric 3.4.2?

Tags: android, robolectric

I have:

```
PackageManager packageManager = androidContext.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
final List appList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(createIntentToLauncherActivity(), 0);

private Intent createIntentToLauncherActivity() {
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
return intent;
}
```

In source code I can mock `packageManager` but I am getting exception for `packageManager.queryIntentActivities(createIntentToLauncherActivity(), 0);`.

I am getting empty applist but I need to set with details like

```
log.d("Package Name: " + appInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
log.d("Activity Name: " + appInfo.activityInfo.name);
log.d("Process Name: " + appInfo.activityInfo.processName);
```

I used

```
List appList = new ArrayList();    
ResolveInfo resolveInfo = new ResolveInfo();
resolveInfo.isDefault = true;
ActivityInfo activityInfo = new ActivityInfo();
activityInfo.packageName = "jp.co.ricoh.advop.simplecopy";
resolveInfo.activityInfo = new ActivityInfo();
resolveInfo.activityInfo = activityInfo;
resolveInfo.activityInfo.name = "Example";
appList.add(resolveInfo);
```

When I add conditions like below to mock `queryIntentActivities` like below:

```
when(shadowApplicationPackageManager.queryIntentActivities(createIntentToLauncherActivity(), 0)).thenReturn(appList);

After setting this I am getting

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue:
    ArrayList cannot be returned by toString()`enter code here`
    toString() should return String
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to decide if your test will be **Robolectric** one without mocking `PackageManager` or it will be JVM and you mock it with **Mockito**.

If you go with **Robolectric** then you need just instruct `ShadowPackageManager`:

```
PackageManager pm = RuntimeEnvironment.applicaition.getPackageManager();
ShadowPackageManager spm = shadowOf(pm);
spm.addResolveInfoForIntent(intent, list);
```

Unfortunately, provided parts of your code don't show where exactly you're getting the error.

I also recommend avoiding Robolectric because of the running time.